# Замена тире на двоеточие, двоеточия — на тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

**Я встретил троих людей: Вову, Васю и Кирилла — сыновей Елены Викторовны.**

"Вова, Вася и Кирилл" — вставное предложение. Я бы хотел, чтобы оно имело присоединительное значение, а потому напишу так:
*Я встретил троих людей — Вову, Васю и Кирилла — сыновей Елены Викторовны.*

Если вставное предложение окружено двумя тире или двоеточиями, допустимо заменить один знак на другой. То есть такая пунктуация допустима:
*Я встретил троих людей — Вову, Васю и Кирилла: сыновей Елены Викторовны.*

Или здесь есть какое-то нарушение?

Answer (score 2):

*Вову, Васю и Кирилла* — это НЕ вставное предложение.

Тире перед рядом однородных членов (*Вову, Васю и Кирилла*) допустимо.
*Сыновей Елены Викторовны* — приложение. Его вполне можно отделить запятой.

***Я встретил троих людей — Вову, Васю и Кирилла, сыновей Елены Викторовны.***

Мне нравится первый вариант, где приложение, находящееся в конце предложения, отделено с помощью тире:

***Я встретил троих людей: Вову, Васю и Кирилла — сыновей Елены Викторовны.***

Answer (score 0):

При изъятии вставного предложения структура не должна нарушаться. Имеем:
*Я встретил троих людей сыновей Елены Викторовны.* || Так не получается.

*Я встретил троих людей — Вову, Васю и Кирилла: сыновей Елены Викторовны.* || Тире в тему, а двоеточие - нет. На основе какого правила оно здесь поставлено?

Замена знаков не делается произвольно.